# How to convert kg to lb and then find the mean and standard deviation?

Tags: r

I'm new with R and Stack Overflow. I am working on a question from the a data that I've been struggle with. The 2015 data comes from https://www.kaggle.com/cdc/behavioral-risk-factor-surveillance-system. It's a large .csv file so I didn't know how to put it on here (my apologizes).
And the codebook is from https://www.cdc.gov/brfss/annual_data/2015/pdf/2015_Calculated_Variables_Version4_08_10_17-508c.pdf.

Q. Compare only those who have and have not had some form of arthritis, rheumatoid arthritis, gout, etc. For those groupings, convert reported weight in kilograms to pounds. Then, compute the mean and standard deviation of the newly created weight in pounds variable. Use the conversion 1KG = 2.20462 LBS. Make sure the units are in pounds, not two decimals implied. The names of the variables should be mean_weight and sd_weight. mean_weight should equal 183.04.

It is suppose to look like this:

| mean_weight | sd_weight |
| --- | --- |
| 183.04 | xx.xx |
| xxx.xx | xx.xx |

My code was:

```
weight_lb <- na.omit((BRFSS2015$WTKG3 * 2.20462)/100)
```

```
Model1<- BRFSS2015%>%
  filter(HAVARTH3 == "1" | HAVARTH3 == "2")%>%
  group_by(HAVARTH3)%>%
  summarise(mean_weight = round(mean(weight_lb), digits = 2), sd_weight = round(sd(weight_lb), digits = 2))%>%
  select(mean_weight, sd_weight)
Model1
```

My Output was:

| mean_weight | sd_weight |
| --- | --- |
| 179.42 | 47.64 |
| 179.42 | 47.64 |

Please help! Thank you.

Comment: you should include `weight_lb` within your data frame; use a `mutate()` step to add it (somewhere before you summarize).

Comment: I tried the `mutate()` but the 4 rows come out as NA.

Comment: Perhaps you should include `na.rm = TRUE` in your `mean` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your code and `mean`s `na.rm = TRUE` argument

```r
library(dplyr)

# options(pillar.sigfig = 7)

BRFSS2015 %>%
  filter(HAVARTH3 == "1" | HAVARTH3 == "2") %>%
  group_by(HAVARTH3) %>%
  mutate(weight_lb = WTKG3 * 2.20462 / 100) %>% 
  summarise(mean_weight = round(mean(weight_lb, na.rm = TRUE), digits = 2), 
            sd_weight = round(sd(weight_lb, na.rm = TRUE), digits = 2)) %>%
  select(mean_weight, sd_weight)
```

we get

```r
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  mean_weight sd_weight
        <dbl>     <dbl>
1      183.04     49.81
2      176.08     46.31
```